# Issues with Cart feature in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, cart

I've managed to get my Cart feature to show up at the bottom of my Foodinfo page, but when I click on the Cart itself it's just a blank page. How can I pass the props to the cart while not having the Card component show up on the Foodinfo page? Goal is to have the Foodinfo page be the parent, and Cart to be the child. Thanks!

Here is my Foodinfo page.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import data from './data.json';
import Cart from './Cart';

export default function Foodinfo() {
    const params = useParams();
    const [item, setItem] = useState(null);
    const { products } = data;
    const [ cartItems, setCartItems ] = useState([]);

    const onAdd = (product) => {
        const exist = cartItems.find((x) => x.id === product.id);
        if (exist) {
          const newCartItems = cartItems.map((x) =>
          x.id === product.id ? { ...exist, qty: exist.qty + 1} : x
          )
          setCartItems(newCartItems)
          localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(newCartItems));
        } else {
          const newCartItems = [...cartItems, { ...product, qty: 1}]
          setCartItems(newCartItems);
          localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(newCartItems));
        }
      }
    
      const onRemove = (product) => {
        const exist = cartItems.find((x) => x.id === product.id);
        if (exist.qty === 1) {
          const newCartItems = cartItems.filter((x) => x.id !== product.id);
          setCartItems(newCartItems)
          localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(newCartItems));
        } else {
          const newCartItems = cartItems.map((x) =>
          x.id === product.id ? { ...exist, qty: exist.qty -1 } : x
          )
          setCartItems(newCartItems)
          localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(newCartItems));
        }
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setCartItems(localStorage.getItem('cartItems') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) 
        : []);
      }, [])
  
    useEffect(() => {
        const idFromUrl = parseInt(params.id, 10);
        const foundItem = data.find((d) => d.id === idFromUrl);
        setItem(foundItem);
    }, [params.id]);
  
    return (
        <div>
            {item ? (
                <div className="flex flex-wrap border-4 border-red-500 rounded-[25px] bg-white mt-12 md:mt-24 mx-auto justify-center max-w-[80%] md:max-w-[50%]">
                    <h2 className="my-auto py-5 mx-auto md:text-2xl">{item.title}</h2>
                    <img src={item.pic} alt={item.name} className="w-[400px] h-[300px] mx-auto pb-5 md:mt-5" />
                  <div className="flex flex-col mx-auto">  
                    <h1 className="font-bold text-center md:my-auto md:text-2xl">Item Info</h1>
                    <p className="my-3 mx-auto text-center md:my-auto md:text-2xl">{item.info}</p>
                    <p className="text-center md:my-auto md:text-2xl md:pb-3"><strong>Single:</strong> {item.single}</p>                    
                    <p className="text-center mb-3 md:my-auto md:text-2xl md:pb-3"><strong>Combo:</strong> {item.combo}</p>      
                    <p className="text-center mb-3 md:my-auto md:text-2xl md:pb-3"><strong>Calories:</strong> {item.calories}</p>            
                  </div>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            )}
              <div className="flex justify-center my-7 space-x-20 text-white font-semibold">
                <Link to="/">
                    <button className="bg-red-500 rounded-3xl w-28 border-2 border-red-700 hover:bg-red-600">Menu</button>
                </Link>
                <Link to="">
                    <button className="bg-red-500 rounded-3xl w-28 border-2 border-red-700 hover:bg-red-600">Add To Cart</button>
                </Link>
              </div>
              <Cart  
                onAdd={onAdd}
                onRemove={onRemove}
                cartItems={cartItems}
              />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is my Cart page.

```
import React from 'react'
 
export default function Cart(props) {

  const { cartItems, onAdd, onRemove } = props;

  // Cart price and tax price
  const itemsPrice = cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.qty * c.price, 0);
  const taxPrice = itemsPrice * 0.14;
  // If cart total is over 2000 it's "free". Otherwise it's $20.
  const shippingPrice = itemsPrice > 2000 ? 0 : 20;
  const totalPrice = itemsPrice + taxPrice + shippingPrice

  return (
    <div className="counter">
      <h1>CART YO</h1>
      <div>
            {cartItems.length === 0 && <div>Cart is empty</div>}
            {cartItems.map((item) => (
                <div key={item.id} >
                    <div>{item.name}</div>
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={() => onRemove(item)}>-</button>
                        <button onClick={() => onAdd(item)}>+</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {item.qty} x ${item.price?.toFixed(2)}
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
            {cartItems.length !== 0 && (
                <div>
                    <hr />
                        <div>
                            <p>Items Price</p>
                            <p>${itemsPrice.toFixed(2)}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>Tax Price</p>
                            <p>${taxPrice.toFixed(2)}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>Shipping Price</p>
                            <p>${shippingPrice.toFixed(2)}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>Total Price</p>
                            <p>${totalPrice.toFixed(2)}</p>
                        </div>
                    <hr />
                        <div>
                            <button onClick={() => alert('Proceed to Checkout!')}>
                                Checkout
                            </button>
                        </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The easiest way is to just use React Context, using this is a way to put things into memory and skip around the need for props.

Comment: Does it seem like more and more people are using useContext and steering away from using Props?